# Virtual memory without secondary storage

Tags: memory, operating-system

Can you have virtual memory without a secondary storage ( hard disk ) ?

Comment: The interviewer is a babbling idiot confusing "swap memory" and "virtual memory". Or maybe that's what he (or she) is expecting you to point out :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a pure sense, yes you can: [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

What makes memory `virtual` is the fact that all memory accesses by the process are intercepted at the CPU level and a hardware [Memory Management Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is used to manage a mapping of the process address space onto the physical memory, no matter where that storage is presently really located.

You can have computing systems with virtual memory that have no `backing storage` (which is what people call it when you can move pages of memory out to disk for later retrieval).

In this case, the virtual memory system is used to allow the OS to intercept and prevent illegal memory references, but not in order to increase the working-set size of processes beyond the amount of installed physical memory.

Comment: "the virtual memory system is used to allow the OS to intercept and prevent illegal memory references" - you don't need virtual memory for that; even my old Z80 generated an interrupt for invalid memory access.  Possible benefits: a fragmented set of physical pages can be presented to software as a contiguous virtual memory space, processes can hardcode memory addresses knowing that from their perspective they're loaded at a fixed address, such fixed addresses can be used even if there are gaps in the physical memory (e.g. stack always growing downwards from 4GB from process perspective)....